# eTag algorithm for multipart S3 uploads in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-s3

I understand, in theory, the algorithm for generating an S3 multi-part upload eTag.  But, I'm not getting the expected results.  Can someone help?

**Theory of eTag for multi-part uploads (at least my understanding)**:

Take the md5 of each upload part and concatenate them.  Then, take the md5 of the concatenated md5s.  Finally, add a "-" and the number of parts uploaded.

***NOTE:  The example below uses made up md5 values.  The resulting md5 is not an actual md5 of the part md5's***

e.g.

- 283771245d05b26c35768d1f182fbac0 - file part 1's md5
- 673c3f1ad03d60ea0f64315095ad7131 - file part 2's md5
- 11c68be603cbe39357a0f93be6ab9e2c - file part 3's md5

**Concatenated md5:**  283771245d05b26c35768d1f182fbac0673c3f1ad03d60ea0f64315095ad713111c68be603cbe39357a0f93be6ab9e2c

**The md5 of the concatenated string above with the dash and number of file parts**:
115671880dfdfe8860d6aabd09139708-3

**To do this in Java I've tried two methods - neither of which returns the correct eTag value**

```
int MB = 1048576;
int bufferSize = 5 * MB;
byte[] buffer = new byte[ bufferSize ];

try {  // String method
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( new File( fileName ) );

    int bytesRead;
    String md5s = "";

    do {
        bytesRead = fis.read( buffer );
        String md5 =  org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex( new String( buffer ) );
        md5s += md5;
    }  while ( bytesRead == bufferSize );

    System.out.println( org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex( md5s ) );
    fis.close();

}
catch( Exception e ) {
    System.out.println( e );
}


try {  //  Byte array method
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( new File( fileName ) );

    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    do {
        bytesRead = fis.read( buffer );
        byteArrayOutputStream.write( org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5( buffer ) );
    }  while ( bytesRead == bufferSize );

    System.out.println( org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex( byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() ) );
    fis.close();
}
catch( Exception e ) {
    System.out.println( e );
}
```

Can anyone spot why neither algorithm is working?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the byte oriented method.

That fails because:

```
}  while ( bytesRead == bufferSize );
```

fails if the file consists of precisely x parts.

Besides that it fails for:

```
byteArrayOutputStream.write( org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5( buffer ) );
```

if the block *isn't fully filled* with bytes, i.e. when the file does not consist of precisely x parts.

In other words, it always fails.